# Why does ammonia causes unsymmetric cleavage of diborane, but carbon monoxide causes symmetric cleavage?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Diborane reacts with Lewis bases to form adducts.

I did some research on my own, and found that ammonia breaks it unsymmetrically but $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{PF3}$ break it symmetrically. I cannot find the reason.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50156/mechanism-for-the-cleavage-of-diborane http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/why-is-diborane-cleaved-symmetrically-by-trimethylamine-but-unsymmetrically-by-a

Comment: Clearly not a duplicate, since "sterics" are no longer a good answer: $\ce{NH3}$ is intermediate in volume between $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{PF3}$.